# What are bases of the image of $φ$ ?What comes from uniqueness of solutions of the linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

m × n matrix A describes a linear map $φ$ $: \mathbb R ^{n}\mapsto\mathbb R ^{m}$.  Examine whether $φ$ is injective, surjective or bijective. What are bases of the image of $φ$ ?What comes from uniqueness of solutions of the linear system?
$A\vec{x} =\vec{b}   $with $ \vec{b}\in \mathbb R ^{m}.$
 I have done that the matrix is injective (rank of A is same as the number of columns. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: No, the rank cannot be four= the number of columns, as it **surely** equals the row rank, which is $\le 2$ . Check your work.

Comment: Okay but how to find bases of the image?

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic theorem that $\;\text{rank}_{col.}\,A=\text{rank}_{row}\,A\;$ for any matrix $\;A\;$.

Since in our case $\;\text{rank}_{row}\,A=2\;$ as both rows are clearly linearly independent, the same is true for the columns of $\;A\;$, and thus **any two** of them which are linearly independent are a basis for Im$\,A\,$ , for example the first and the third one:

$$\text{Im}\,A=\text{Span}\,\left\{\;\binom10\;,\;\;\binom03\;\right\}$$

Comment: Since $m=2=\dim\operatorname{im}A$, you might as well take the standard basis for the image.

Comment: @amd Thank you. Indeed so, yet I wanted on purpose to use columns from the matrix as the asker doesn't seem to know all this.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. It’s not true, however, that *any* two columns will form a basis for the image—the first and second columns aren’t linearly independent. The usual method that’s taught is to take the columns in the original matrix that correspond to columns with pivots in its rref, although I prefer column reduction as that usually produces a more useful set of vectors.

Comment: @amd Thank you, you're right. I ommited "linearly independent", edited now.